# How to indicate a relationship between a class (or interface) and a interface that is used a type parameter in function

Tags: uml, class-diagram

I can't find the anwser myself so I will try it here.

I'm working on an assignment and I'm not sure how to draw a certain relationship between a class (or interface) and an interface that is used a parameter in a method of said class. TBH I reversed engineerd it from java code (we received as assignment) but it seems to me that it is missing relationships, specifically the relationships I mention above.

I have some examples for this:

[image]

You see that Observer Type is used in Subject's methods as a parameter.

[image]

Same as above, MQTTClientServer uses the interface type MQTTCallback in its subscribe function.

I'm really scratching my head over this one, I would assume because it's an interface the implementation of the interface would dictate where the relation would actually be implemented. But I can't find any theoratical information on how these relationships should penned down.

Answer (score 2):

Using an interface or a class as type of a parameter is implying a UML-usage. It can explicitly be modeled with a dashed arrow and the keyword «use» from the class with the operation to the interface or class used as type.

The implementation will later specify, how exactly the interface or class is used, but that doesn't change the usage relationship.

In the case of parameters the arrow might seem redundant, because using a type is already a usage. However, visualizing the relationship graphically can help to minimize unwanted relationships. Also if the interface or class is used internally, it would not be visible without modeling this relationship.

Edit: The keyword is «use», not «usage», as I have previously written.

Comment: I usually stay with a simple dependency (so without stereotype) in such cases. It's not wrong with «use», though. From my POV a dependency already implies a use since what else would the dependency be if not being a use indication? Sort of a philosophical question, I know.

Comment: I agree that a simple dependency works in this case. However, why not be more specific, when it clearly _is_ a usage. One advantage is, at least for interfaces, that as a notational option a usage can be shown with the lolly notation as a socket symbol. Please note that it is not a stereotype, even though its keyword is written in guillemets. It is a fully fledged metaclass. Not, that it would make much of a difference here, but I think it is worth mentioning.

Comment: Once more fooled by the keyword/stereotype ambiguity. I wonder who at OMG is responsible for that...

Comment: Actually, since both stereotypes and metaclasses are on the metalevel the reader of a diagram doesn't need to know, which it is. Therefore, I think it makes sense not to have a different notation.

Comment: Maybe for the reader. But maintainers of profiles would not agree, I guess.